# Enable/disable WPF controls using RadioButtons in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, radio-button

My problem is that I have a set of RadioButtons and I want to disable another control depending on which RadioButton is selected.

It is important that I can disable the control if of one of **several** RadioButton is selected.

E.g.

```
[] Enabled one
[] Enabled two
[] Disabled one
[] Disabled two
```

The control should be disabled if one of the last two buttons are selected.

**Note**

I intend to answer this question myself ([Which should be ok according to this link)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) but I will accept other answers if they solve the problem in a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is the only place where you need it, then it is ok to use your simple solution, but I think in a real application you will probably face this situation many times, so I prefer to use a general solution to make things simpler.
For me, I will use a MultiConverter to calculate a result boolean from several other booleans using logical `OR`, like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:MultiBoolOrConverter x:Key="MultiBoolOrConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton GroupName="group" x:Name="enabledOne">Enabled one</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton GroupName="group" x:Name="enabledTwo">Enabled two</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton GroupName="group" x:Name="disabledOne">Disabled one</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton GroupName="group" x:Name="disabledTwo">Disabled two</RadioButton>

<TextBox Text="Test">   
    <TextBox.IsEnabled>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBoolOrConverter}">
            <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="enabledOne" />
            <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="enabledTwo" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.IsEnabled>
</TextBox>

</StackPanel>
```

and the used `MultiBoolOrConverter.cs` converter class:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace StackOverFlowTest.Converters
{
    class MultiBoolOrConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return values.Cast<bool>().Any(value => value);
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

you also may face a situation where you need to use `AND` instead of `OR` , here is the `MultiBoolAndConverter` converter:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace StackOverFlowTest.Converters
{
    class MultiBoolAndConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return values.Cast<bool>().All(value => value);
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I wish this will help you.

**UPDATE ---------------------**

In my previous solution, I have used the logic:

`The control should be enabled if one of the first two buttons are selected.`

Instead of what you have asked literally:

`The control should be disabled if one of the last two buttons are selected.`

It is working of course, but if you want it exactly as you’ve described then the code will need little change to use a converter to negate `IsChecked` boolean value:

```
<Window.Resources>
<converters:MultiBoolAndConverter x:Key="MultiBoolAndConverter" />
<converters:BoolNegationConverter x:Key="BoolNegationConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton GroupName="group" x:Name="enabledOne">Enabled one</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton GroupName="group" x:Name="enabledTwo">Enabled two</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton GroupName="group" x:Name="disabledOne">Disabled one</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton GroupName="group" x:Name="disabledTwo">Disabled two</RadioButton>

<TextBox Text="Test">   
    <TextBox.IsEnabled>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBoolAndConverter}">
            <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="disabledOne" Converter="{StaticResource BoolNegationConverter}" />
            <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="disabledTwo" Converter="{StaticResource BoolNegationConverter}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.IsEnabled>
</TextBox>

</StackPanel>
```

`BoolNegationConverter.cs` :

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace StackOverFlowTest.Converters
{
    class BoolNegationConverter: IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return !(value is bool && (bool)value);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return !(value is bool && (bool)value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be my preferred solution as well. Using the multivalueconverter allows you to expand this behavior to an unlimited number of booleans

Comment: This is actually a much neater solution than mine. As you say it is useable in more situations. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2):

The solution I came up with is:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="enableDisableStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=disabledOne}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=disabledTwo}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton GroupName="group" x:Name="enabledOne">Enabled one</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton GroupName="group" x:Name="enabledTwo">Enabled two</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton GroupName="group" x:Name="disabledOne">Disabled one</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton GroupName="group" x:Name="disabledTwo">Disabled two</RadioButton>

    <TextBox Text="Test" Style="{StaticResource enableDisableStyle}" />
</StackPanel>
```

I will not mark my own answer as accepted until I'm convinced it is the best solution.